# iOS image viewer or preview exact like photos app using collection view (paging enabled) with minimum line spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to develop the preview exact like iOS photos app have. If we select any image from the photos app then it will be displayed in full screen(having `imageview` with `aspect fit`). Now If we swipe our finger then next cell will displayed and meanwhile we can see the line spacing between then cells. I want exact effect like that using collection view only. I don't want to use any libraries. In my case what is happening is once I scroll to next page I found line spacing on left side like below screenshots.

I have tried many solutions like manually scroll to specific `index path` from `scrollview delegate methods` but behavior was not smooth.

Effects that I am getting are as below,

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, when I leave my finger image should set `edge to edge`.

My current code is like,

in viewdidload,

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20.0
    layout.itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

and I have implemented necessary `datasource methods` for the collection view!

In short I want `edge to edge scrolling` with `paging effect` having `minimum line space of 20` between cells in `collectionview`. That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately with paging enabled the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` doesn't take the spacing into account.  You are probably going to have to use a custom layout.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth: Yeah! Tha's what I was thinking but I got simple idea to set `sectionInset` and it does a trick! You can check my answer! And thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Nice that works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ohh, It was so easy!

I found the solution by doing the trick like,

I have increase the width of collection view 20 pixel larger then screen width. So, my collection view's leading constrait's constant is `-10` and trailing constraint is also `-10` and I have set the `sectionInset` of the `flowlayout` of the `collectionview` to `(0, 10, 0, 10)`.

So my storyboard setup is like,

[image]

and my setup for `collectionview` is like,

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20.0
    layout.itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)   // added this

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

and that's it!